# Quickly SSH into another box over SSH

Tags: ssh

I need to upload and compile stuff on a remote machine that is only reachable inside a specific network that I can access over SSH.

So for example I perform the following steps:

```
me@mymachine$ ssh user@network_gateway
user@network_gateway$ ssh seconduser@targetmachine
seconduser@targetmachine$ #do stuff
```

Is there a way to make my local machine aware of the tunneling without undergoing the trouble of connecting to the network gateway every time?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't setup a VPN?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can configure your `.ssh/config` to provide a tunnel automatically for the `targetmachine`. For this to work passwordlessly, you need to set up public key authentication in both hosts and agent forwarding in the gateway, though.

Set it up so a connection to `targetmachine` is proxied through `network_gateway`:

```
Host targetmachine
  HostName targetmachine.company.com
  ProxyCommand ssh network_gateway -W %h:%p
```

Then you can issue:

```
$ ssh targetmachine
```

to connect directly. There's more info in the `ssh_config(5)` manpage.

Comment: Alternatively you can forward ports from `network_gateway`.

Comment: I ended up using ssh_config ProxyJump from this answer: https://serverfault.com/a/1143238/961076

Answer (score 2):

SSH will take a command to be executed on the remote machine. For example, to SSH into server2 via server1:

```
ssh alice@server1 "ssh bob@server2"
```

Then you will be able to type commands into server2's prompt.

If you want to get even more fancy, you can nest them:

```
ssh alice@server1 "ssh bob@server2 \"cd myproject && git pull origin master && make all\""
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a script like [ssh-chain](https://github.com/ryancdotorg/ssh-chain) to make your life easier.

No idea if it supports sftp transfers, though.