# ssh proxyjump command to config file

Tags: linux, ssh, proxy, ssh-tunnel

I use a ssh command for logging into a remote node using an intermediate node via proxyjump. The remote and intermediate nodes are Linux servers, and my client is a Macbook. This command works, and it looks like:

`ssh -i .ssh/id_file -J user1@jump_node -A -D remote_port user2@remote_node`

where I replace jump_node and remote_node with the hostnames of intermediate and remote nodes, and remote_port with the sshd port on remote_node.

**My first and main question is: how to make this command into a config section** that I can put in my .ssh/config file? I looked at ssh man page and could not get the corresponding config options for `-D` and `-A` flags (I guess `ForwardAgent yes` for `-A`?). Could someone please explain these flags and how to make a correct config section out of this command?

---

My other question is less important, but would help me understand what is going on here. **This second question is about an error I get when I issue a slightly different command.**

Most documentation I read online suggest using a command like this:

`ssh -i .ssh/id_file -J user1@jump_node user2@remote_node:remote_port`

but when I try this command (both with and without the `-A` flag), I get the following error:

```
channel 0: open failed: connect failed: Name or service not known
stdio forwarding failed
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535
```

I could not figure out what this error means and if it has some hints I could use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`man 5 ssh_config`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#ProxyJump):

```
ForwardAgent yes
IdentityFile .ssh/id_file

Host jump_node
    User user1

Host remote_node
   ProxyJump jump_node
   User user2
```

and just run `ssh remote_node`.

You can even build a chain this way, if you also specify (another) `ProxyJump` for the `jump_node` too.

---

The second problem is that `ssh user2@remote_node:remote_port` is incorrect syntax. The error message states `Name or service not known`, because it attempted (and failed) to resolve `remote_node:remote_port` as a host name (yes, with embedded colon), not `remote_node` as you might expect. Try to run same thing without `-J`, the error message will be slightly more clear.

I'd interpret this as an attempt to specify a port where SSH server is listening on the remote node; for that, use `-p` command-line parameter or `Port` host entry option in a config file.

Also this has nothing in common with the `-D` command-line switch. And it's argument is not a "remote port". Rather, that switch does entirely different thing, namely, it makes the SSH client to *listen* on the specified port *on the local machine* and accept SOCKS connections, and the remote will be used as an exit node. You can, for example, configure it in the local browser, so it will access the internet through the SSH tunnel and third parties (web servers) will see your connections as coming from remote host's IP; nobody will see your "real" IP, except the SSH server (which will see jump server's address in this case, though). To set *this* in the config, you use `DynamicForward` option in the config file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I noticed that on your suggested config entry, there is no port_number? My command doesn't work without the port number.

Comment: Would you mind reading the whole answer?

Comment: I read your whole answer before posting and tried the ```-p``` option as well. But this command doesn't work: ```ssh -i .ssh/id_file -J user1@jump_node -A -p remote_port user2@remote_node```. It asks me to accept the fingerprint of the host, then asks me for password. In my command that works (with a ```-D remote_port``` flag), a password is never asked.

Comment: That means there are SSH servers on the address "remote_node" both on "port_number" and on the default port (22); you have previously accepted a host key and installed your auth key to the one listening on port 22. **Argument of -D is not a remote port, RTFM!** Admin of the target_node should explain why is there are SSH servers on different ports; maybe the other port is NATed to some other machine.

Comment: Would you mind reading the **whole** answer? You just proved you hadn't yet! It's even highlighted!

Comment: Edited for clarity: You're right, Thank you! I removed any ```remote_port``` from my command, and it still works, meaning that I am able to ssh into port 22, and not use my specific sshd daemon running on ```remote_port```.

Comment: It is not needed, and even insecure, to use ForwardAgent with ProxyJump. It used to be needed with ProxyCommand